# How to import database to a phpadmin that has import limit

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I am importing my old database to a new host. But that host's phpmyadmin has the import limit which is 32mb while my database is about 100mb

I tried all the php.ini file but it does not work

```
upload_max_filesize = 120M

post_max_size = 120M
```

Later i found out that if i want to increase it i have to ask the host. So i mailed and asked them to increase the limit.

Just in case their respond taking too slow. I want to ask if i can seperate my database into small parts and import them to the new host's database with out messing it up.

If it is possible. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try external app like MySQL Workbench to connect with your db?

Comment: You could run `mysql dump` and export individual tables from the database. Usually hosting companies have a tool to transfer data

Comment: What format is your data in currently that you want to import?

Comment: Thank you for responding everyone. I am using the phpmyadmin i don't know what is the format actually. Maybe all the tables. I will try to figure it out about mysql dump and mysql workbench. Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SQL file splitting tool like [this one](https://www.philiplb.de/sqldumpsplitter3/). It splits one large SQL file into smaller batches of a pre-defined size, which could go under your limit of 32MB.

Comment: I tried your advices and spilit it into different parts. But when i import it here are what it said. What should i do.

```SQL query:


CREATE TABLE `ps_access` (
  `id_profile` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_authorization_role` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_0900_ai_ci

MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected```

Comment: In PMA, click on the database you want to import the files onto. You could also add "USE database_name;" at the beginning of each file.